# mongodb: aggregates over a list contained in each document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, nosql

I have currently reading [the mongoDb aggregation introduction](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/). The examples show how the aggregation operation is powerful, for example, to sum certain values across a subset of documents in a collection.

What I need is actually a bit different: I need to perform the same operation within a list that is contained in each document of a collection. In this way I would still get an element for each document that is contained in the collection, but the lists that are contained in each document would be collapsed, by summation on a certain field contained in the sub-documents contained in the list.

Is this possible with normal pipeline/aggregation operations in MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) operator allows to expand a list contained in a document across several documents.

For example, the following query just expands the `sessions` list into several documents, that can be used, afterwards, for an aggregation over the `Ts` field:

```
db.userStats.aggregate([
    { $match: {"u":{ "$in": [1,2,3,4,5] }}},
    { $unwind: "$sessions" },
    { $group: { _id:"$u" , total: { $sum: "$sessions.Ts"}}},
])
```

Comment: Does this solve your problem? If so you should mark your answer as accepted. Using `$unwind` with `$group` and `$sum` will let you sum the elements in an array in a document.

Comment: sure, but I have to wait 2 days before accepting my own answer

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to do a $project, possibly followed by a $group if you'd prefer to collapse all the results into a single document.  Something like:

```
db.userStats.aggregate([
    { $match: {"u":{ "$in": [1,2,3,4,5] }}},
    { $project: { total: { $sum: "$sessions.Ts"}}},
    { $group: { _id:"$u" , total: { $first: "$total" }}},
])
```

Comment: [`$sum`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) is an accumulator that's only available in the group stage of an aggregation pipeline.

Comment: Oh, that explains why you wanted to use $unwind, then.  I wonder how they'd respond to a feature request to support accumulators in $project...